# Default Name in Page Title

Tags: magento2

I am trying to figure how to have by default all my pages display "| Company Name" in the page title. Each product, category and any other pages I have on the site once I add the Meta Title for each of the pages the feature | Company name is automatically added to the title of each page so I ant have to manually type it in every time

I have done this in my two previous Magneto 1 sites and want to create this in my new M2 site. I cannot remember where and how this was created.

Answer (score 2):

**Page Title Prefix**:

- **Scope:** Store View
- **Description:** A prefix can be added before the title to create a two- or three-part title. A vertical bar or colon can be used as a separator at the end of the prefix to differentiate it from the text of the main title.
- **Path:** Admin sidebar > Content > Design > Configuration > Edit(Store View) > Other Settings > HTML Head > Page Title Prefix

**Page Title Suffix:**

- **Scope:** Store View
- **Description:** A suffix can be added after the title to create a two-or
  three part title. A vertical bar or colon can be used as a separator at the end of the prefix to differentiate it from the text of the main title.
- **Path:** Admin sidebar > Content > Design > Configuration > Edit(Store View) > Other Settings > HTML Head > Page Title Suffix

For more detail, please refer the [Magento Docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/html-head.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this post, http://mageguides.com/how-to-configure-html-head-in-magento-2-page-setup/ it has Title prefix and suffix fields